# How to prevent other apps from snatching the camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

In my Android application, I am using Camera 1 API to preview as well as record camera input.

Here are relevant code snippets. Full explanation is at https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect#java.

```
 public void surfaceChanged(...) {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
    requestLayout();
    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

    mCamera.startPreview();
 }

 public void surfaceDestroyed(...) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
 }
```

This all works fine even if I bring up another app on top of this app. When I bring back my app, the camera continues to work.

The problem comes in when I bring up another app that actually starts a camera. If I close this other app and bring my app back up, `mCamera.getParameters` in `SurfaceChanged` throws an exception.

Is there a way to prevent my camera that is in use from being snatched away by another application? If not, is there a better way to deal with this situation? I tried `Camera.reconnect()` in `SurfaceChanged` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Android M, the foreground application is always able to take control of the camera, even if a previous application is using the camera in the background.

For the old camera API, [sign up](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera#setErrorCallback(android.hardware.Camera.ErrorCallback)) to listen to the [ErrorCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.ErrorCallback).  If you get disconnected from the device while in the background, you'll receive a callback on this method.  The error code (for backwards-compatibility reasons) is likely going to be UNKNOWN, but it doesn't really matter - any error means you'll want to reopen the camera.

Then you'll know you need to reopen the camera once you're in the foreground.

In addition, starting with Android Pie (9.0), background applications will be disconnected from the camera after a few seconds of being in the background, unless they start a foreground service with a notification.  This is for privacy reasons, and is recommended best practice even on older Android releases.